# after_create_commit doesn't execute some methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

So I have this ruby on rails model class:

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home_player, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "home_player_user_id", optional: true
  belongs_to :away_player, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "away_player_user_id", optional: true
  belongs_to :winner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "winner_user_id", optional: true
  belongs_to :round

  has_one :match_chat

  after_create_commit :create_match_chat

  def create_match_chat
    MatchChat.create(
        title: "Chat##{id} #{home_player.try(:userName).presence || 'Free Win'} vs. #{away_player.try(:userName).presence || 'Free Win'}",
        match_id: id
    )

    if home_player == nil
      send_result_message("We detected a free win. Setting free win user result to LOST")
      update_attribute(:home_score, -2)
      save
    end

    if away_player == nil
      send_result_message("We detected a free win. Setting free win user result to LOST")
      update_attribute(:away_score, -2)
      save
    end

    generate_match_code

    send_welcome_message("Welcome to your game. Please enter the code 
       above in order to get matched up and play your game. For 
       coordination please use the Chat below.")
  end


  def generate_match_code
    update_attribute(:first_pokemon, rand(10) + 1)
    update_attribute(:second_pokemon, rand(10) + 1)
    update_attribute(:third_pokemon, rand(10) + 1)
  end

  def send_welcome_message(message)
    Message.create(body: "SYSTEM: #{message}", user_id: 1, match_chat:
        match_chat)
  end

  def send_result_message(message)
    Message.create(body: "FREE WIN: #{message}", user_id: 1, match_chat:
        match_chat)
  end
end
```

When testing this locally on development and production environment it works completely fine and everything gets executed.

However, when I deploy this to the webserver (nginx+passenger) only parts of the create_match_chat gets executed. So the MatchChat gets created, but the match code doesn't get changed with generate_match_code

I tried to read but didn't find anything why this could be happening.

I am using rails 5.2.1 with ruby 2.5.1

Any clues?

**UPDATE**

```
match = Match.new
match.home_player_user_id = home
match.away_player_user_id = away
match.round_id = id
match.first_pokemon = first_pokemon
match.second_pokemon = second_pokemon
match.third_pokemon = third_pokemon
match.save!
```

Even doing this in the most manual way possible doesn't seem to have any effect..

`D, [2018-11-25T09:45:03.240848 #4994] DEBUG -- :   Match Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "matches" ("away_player_user_id", "round_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["away_player_user_id", 1], ["round_id", 20], ["created_at", "2018-11-25 08:45:03.239943"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-25 08:45:03.239943"]]`

Seems like it's not using new queries, but always a really old one. It's super weird and I really need some help with this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that nginx / passenger was not reloading the changes correctly :/ figured that out after rebooting the server

Answer (score 0):

I would start with changing `update_attribute` to `update!`. You do not know what happens because `update_attribute` skips validation, so in case of a validation error, the object is not updated, and you do not get an exception ([documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute))

After changing the code, I would use production DB dump locally to replicate the issue.

Good luck.

Comment: I changed it to `update!`, however it still doesn't do it, nor does it show up in the logs that it even tries to do that... Other stuff I'm doing in this method gets executed. `send_welcome_message` and `generate_match_code ` don't get executed for some reason :/ on development and on my machine in production it works

Comment: Also if I try to call the `Match.create()` from the `rails c` and it inserts everything as I want...only when the app calls it itself it breaks, but only partially...really confusing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `save` after `update_attribute`.

I'd recommend you to use `update_column` instead which does not trigger callbacks and does not change `updated_at` field (it will be faster since you just crated the record and you can be sure it's persisted).

You can use the shorthand `create_match_chat(title: ....)` provided by activerecord too.

Does the error depend on home_player or away_player being or not being nil? What I'm suspecting is that something fails on `send_result_message` and the rest of the code does not work but that would make no sense if the problem happens even if home/away are not nil. Try commenting some lines of the code until you can narrow it down to the exact line.

Comment: I tried to update the match code first as the first thing... it just doesn't get called, I don't understand why? Locally everything works fine... :(((

Answer (score 0):

I also suspect that `send_welcome_message` is not working.

Inside the method try `create!` instead of `create` so an error is thrown and you can understand if anything went wrong there.